# Cleanup Github account

Tags: github

I created a Github account earlier this year when I first started programming and didn't really know what I was doing and now I'm wonder if there is a way I can tidy up my account.  I would like to create a repository and move all of my class projects into it, similar to throwing a bunch of files on your desktop and then cleaning it up by creating folders to drop the files into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

I recommend you start by downloading [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), which is a user interface that will allow you to manage your Git repositories.

Works on Windows and OSX.